# How to execute the policy: "carrot and stick" policy with employees. Is it effective in retention?

Tags: management, teamwork

We are a startup and the team consists mostly of freshers. It's a team of 10 where I lead them technically. Recently the team is going through high attrition (this year 4 left).

The neighboring team's attrition is 0 and I often see the manager speak of the "carrot and stick" policy he employs. He was also warning not to over pamper the employees with it, or micromanage them;.

So I wanted to know any general guidelines - like at what stages and how do effective managers show 'carrots' to the employees to motivate them? Are there any standard approaches or rules-of-thumb to follow? Any guidelines to know that we are overdoing it?

Comment: There are entire books written on these subjects, I'm not sure if it can be summarized down to just an answer.

Comment: A start-up is a different beast from an established company. People are attracted to working in start-ups for the fast-paced nature, inspiring leadership and dynamic workload. Cash is generally limited in the early stages of a start-up so carrots are limited, especially if the owner is unwilling to release equity. High attrition is expected in start-ups due to the nature of the work and large number of unknowns.

Comment: I find the carrot and stick analogy a little demeaning. I would call it "advancement and accountability". As an employee I want to be held accountable for the things I did. The good and the bad. That's your "stick" The carrot is the advancement. At any point I want to know what it takes for me to advance (get the bonus, get the higher salary, get the promotion). If I have nothing to work towards (no carrot), I'm not motivated and will only work to avoid the stick.

Comment: **at what stages and how do effective managers show carrots?** - Show them? Or give them? If you're merely showing them carrots and not giving them carrots then your management amounts to "a stick and a stick". If you're going to hold them accountable then you also need to reward them.

Comment: I definitely agree with @Erik. Managing staff is a fundamental part of running a business or team, requiring understanding of people, psychology, law, and business practices, and if you don't know all that, you're not going to last. There are books, but also consultants and training schemes for wannabe managers, as well as trained HR professionals.

Comment: @joeqwerty - the day my manager shows me his carrot is the day I leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what techniques you employ, there are some more basic elements of motivation that if you don't employ, nothing else will work

- Set clear goals and expectations
- Set clear consequences (both good and bad)
- **BE CONSISTENT AND CONFIDENT**
- Keep your finger on the pulse of what is going on with your team
- Maintain professional distance
- Be fair

Your colleague is right.  You can neither micromanage nor coddle your team.  Either one sends a clear message that you are not treating them as responsible adults.

I suspect that you don't have your footing as a lead, as of yet, and you are shifting from being overbearing to being a pushover.  That is the worst case scenario because people can handle a nice boss or a tough boss, but they can't deal with an **inconsistent** boss.  When I have managed people, I have taken the more "carrot" approach.  I take the approach that a manager/lead position is one of an expeditor.  But I prefer to work for a boss with a more "stick" approach.

Again, it doesn't matter which you chose so long as people know what to expect from you and what you expect from them.  There is no proper amount of rewards or penalties to properly motivate people.  Some people are motivated by "attaboy"s some are motivated by being taken out to the woodshed every so often.

**TLDR:  Consistency and clear expectations are more important than the carrot or the stick.**

Answer (score 14):

Various share-related schemes are often used as a "carrot" in startups - where new members of staff are given shares (or options) that will increase in value over time, or that they are only get after staying with the company for a defined period of time. This encourages them both to stay (so they get the options), but also means that their total remuneration (or the value of their shares/options) is linked to how successful the company is. A simpler version it this would be retention bonuses (such as paying people a fixed bonus after X months or years).

I've also seen companies use a "stick" approach, where they enforce financial penalties on staff who leave soon after starting (such as having to repay the costs of training courses, exams, etc). They can be difficult to enforce though, and could result in your company getting a very bad reputation - so think *very* carefully before something like that.

But if you're losing 40% of your team in a year, that's a pretty bad sign, and suggests significant problems with either your hiring, your salaries, or your working environment. Before you can start thinking about how to motivate and retain people, you need to understand *why* they're leaving in the first place.

Comment: +1.  You can’t just cargo cult some (poorly understood) approach on top of your unclear problem.  Figure out the problem then figure out the fix.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.  The rest of this answer is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: In general terms, people leave a company mostly due to issues with their employer, not anything that can be fixed by offering them a "carrot". "Freshers" may have different issues with a situation than experienced developers.

Comment: "stick" approaches are also likely to fall foul of employment law in jurisdictions which have meaningful protection for workers: you can't just take benefits away, cut pay, reassign to menial roles, etc. It definitely sounds a troubled business - the way to retain talent is to reward and treat well, not to put them in fear - in the latter case they'll leave as soon as they have somewhere to go.

Comment: 40% turnover p.a. would mean that the average time is, what, 2½ years? Isn't that a reasonable time for a young employee in a fast-moving environment like a start-up?

Comment: @gidds 10-15% would be more normal. But when another similar team in the organisation hasn't lost any staff in the same time period, it suggests that something is wrong with OPs team. It's certainly usual to lose some staff, but it's going to get very expensive constantly hiring and training at that rate.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any standard approaches or rules-of-thumb to follow?

No.

> Any guidelines to know that we are overdoing it?

An attrition rate 40% tells you that you are doing something wrong.

> how do effective managers show 'carrots' to the employees to motivate them?

You are blindly grasping at a solution without first determining what the problem is. People leave for all sorts of reasons. Unless you know what the key issues are you can't find a solution. Fix your communication first.

1. Make sure you have regular 1:1s. Ask about how they are doing and what are they struggling with and what there frustrations are.
2. Listen carefully, ask open ended follow up question and don't judge, argue or jump into "fix it" mode.
3. Build trust: stick to your commitments, be consistent, don't blame, support your people when they screw up or need help, be reliable.

Once you you have an open line with your team, you can start working the specific problem, whatever it may be. A cookie cutter approach like "stick and carrot" will not work.